# copying all the elements of a folder into another folder using a loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I want to copy all the files of a folder into some other folders using batch script. Say, I have two folders named folder1 and folder2. these two folders are located in C:\Users\xyz . I want  to copy the elements of another folder (say, folder3 which is located in C:\Users\abc\def) into these two folders. I have made the following script but nothing is copied. My sample batch file is as follows:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,2) DO (
 xcopy /s C:\Users\abc\def\folder3 C:\Users\xyz\folder%%A
)
```

is there anything wrong in the batch file?

Answer (score 1):

```
 xcopy /s C:\Users\abc\def\folder3\*.* C:\Users\xyz\folder%%A\
```

where `*.*` is an appropriate filemask and the final `\` in the destination name tells `cmd` that the destination is a directory.

Comment: still nothing is being copied @Magoo

Comment: Works perfectly happily for me. The directorynames you've provided appear artifical. Perhaps if you were to reveal the true data, we'd be able to solve the problem.

Comment: @aschipfl : certainly, but not in the problem as posed. Hence the desiability of posting code as-is with minimal changes to disguise sensitive data. In this case, the actual path(s) would logically actually contain separators and "simplifying" the problem conceals the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this command line in the batch file:

```
for /L %%A in(1,1,2) do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\Users\abc\def\folder3" "C:\Users\xyz\folder%%A\" /C /G /H /I /K /R /Q /S /Y >nul
```

I enclosed both directory paths in double quotes in case of real paths contain 1 or more spaces or other special characters which require double quotes. The last paragraph on last help page output by running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` outputs on which characters in a directory/file name double quotes are required around the complete directory/file name.

The target path ends with a backslash to make it clear for console application `xcopy` that the target is a directory and not a file. Together with the redundant `/I` the target directory is created if not existing already.

For details on the options used on `xcopy` open a command prompt window and run `xcopy /?`. This outputs the help for this console application in the command prompt window. On Windows running a command or console application with `/?` as parameter outputs in general the help for the command/application.

**Note:** The copying from one user profile directory to another user profile directory requires local administrator privileges. Each user profile directory is by default protected for exclusive usage of the owning user. Therefore I suggest to open a command prompt window and execute in this window:

```
for /L %A in(1,1,2) do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\Users\abc\def\folder3" "C:\Users\xyz\folder%A\" /C /G /H /I /K /R /S /Y
```

You can see if that works with just `%A` as required on command line instead of `%%A` as required in batch files and without `/Q` (quiet copying) and without `>nul` (redirection of success messages to device **NUL** to suppress them). Or when it does not work, you can see why it does not work as the error message can be viewed on running a command or a batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on a batch file because the console window keeps open.

Comment: The `%SystemRoot%\System32\` prefix should not be necessary unless the standard `PATH` settings are not overwritten unintentionally. Appending a backslash and provifing the `/I` switch are redundant...

Comment: @aschipfl Both are right, but it is better to be on safe side. A colleague has once installed AVRStudio years ago which __prepended__ `PATH` by the `bin` directory of AVRStudio and suddenly the domain login batch script did not work anymore. Reason: AVRStudio's `bin` directory contained a `find.exe` and a `findstr.exe` which were ported from Unix working different than Windows `find.exe` and `findstr.exe`. This was the moment from which I started specifying standard Windows console applications with full path and file extension for not depending on `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.

Comment: @aschipfl `/I` is indeed necessary only copying multiple files or an entire directory and target path is not ending with a backslash. `/I` is not enough on copying just a single file, i.e. `xcopy %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe C:\Temp\Test /I` as this results nevertheless for asking if `C:\Temp\Test` is a file or directory. That is correct according to explanation of `/I`. So in general it is always better to specify a target directory with a backslash at end as this works for copying a single file and also for multiple files/directories.